# Oracle - Maximum year query error

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
select * from 
             (    
                select add_months(sysdate,-2)dt from dual
                union
                select add_months(sysdate,-1) from dual
                union
                select add_months(sysdate,2)from dual
                union
                select add_months(sysdate,3) from dual
             )
```

[image: Result]

i want to maximum year of minimum date (" `22.02.2012 12:02:08` ")
How to make this?

Comment: Use `UNION ALL` not `UNION`, `UNION` is slower because it explicitly removes duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this one:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT add_months(sysdate,-2)dt from dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT add_months(sysdate,-1) from dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT add_months(sysdate,2)from dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT add_months(sysdate,3) from dual
    ORDER BY trunc(dt,'YEAR') DESC, trunc(dt,'MONTH') ASC
)
WHERE rownum = 1
```

Comment: +1 because I knew it must be possible to formulate the query the way you did, but was myself too lazy to do so!

Answer (score 2):

use `select max(dt)` instead of `select *`

**Edit**: after rereading your question and comparing your desired output, you 
probably want *the minimum date of the dates within the maximum year*.

In that case, the statement will be

```
with dates as
         (    
            select add_months(sysdate,-2)dt from dual
            union
            select add_months(sysdate,-1) from dual
            union
            select add_months(sysdate,2)from dual
            union
            select add_months(sysdate,3) from dual
         )
      select min(dt) from dates 
        where trunc(dt,'YYYY') = (select max(trunc(dt, 'YYYY')) from dates)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether that's what you're looking for. The question wasn't really clear to me.

```
SELECT MIN(dt) FROM 
(SELECT add_months(SYSDATE, -2) dt
    FROM dual
    UNION
    SELECT add_months(SYSDATE, -1)
      FROM dual
    UNION
    SELECT add_months(SYSDATE, 2)
      FROM dual
    UNION
    SELECT add_months(SYSDATE, 3) FROM dual)
WHERE trunc(dt, 'YYYY') > trunc(SYSDATE, 'YYYY');
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess René's post does what you need. I keep forgetting about the `with`